# scanner i java doesn't work for all inputs

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to read several things ( long, string ) from console but I don't know why for, for example just several first input it works and then it doesn't work for others:
below is the code what I'm talking about, it doesn't ask for adress

```
    public void getInfo(PhoneBook PB)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\n");
    String c1 = "yes";
    do {

        System.out.print("Name:");
        PB.setName(keyboard.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Family:");
        PB.setFamily(keyboard.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Address:");
        PB.setAddress(keyboard.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Number:");
        PB.setNumber(keyboard.nextLong());

        System.out.println("Do you want to continue(yes/no)");
        c1 = keyboard.nextLine();
        phoneBooks.add(PB);
    }while (c1.equals("yes"));
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `nextLong()` (or `nextInt()`, `nextDouble()`, `next()`...), you are reading in a *token* with the Scanner, but are not reading in the end-of-line (EOL) token, thus leaving it dangling. This dangling EOL token will then be scooped up immediately with your next call to `nextLine()`, and so that call will not get the user's input, messing your program up. To fix this, add an additional call to `nextLine()`after getting your `nextLong()`, ignoring any result returned since it will just be the EOL token.

So change this:

```
System.out.print("Number:");
PB.setNumber(keyboard.nextLong());

System.out.println("Do you want to continue(yes/no)");
c1 = keyboard.nextLine();
```

to this:

```
System.out.print("Number:");
PB.setNumber(keyboard.nextLong());

keyboard.nextLine():  // **** add this ****

System.out.println("Do you want to continue(yes/no)");
c1 = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Comment: sorry would you please explain a little more the word "swallow" that you use, you mean that we should get the end-of-line characters in scanners?